# few doubts about pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have been attending lectures of 'programming paradigms' by Stanford University. There I encountered the following code:

```
int l = 10;
float m = *(float*)&l;
```

I know that first casting is done and then dereferencing is done.
How is the value assigned to `m`? What is special about this kind of casting i.e a simple casting can be done by simply having `(float)`.

What is special about this casting and How is a value assigned to a variable?

**Note**: This code may be for only theoretical use but I want to understand the concept underlying it.

Comment: This is probably undefined behavior for violating the [aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). It might make a cup of tea for you or it might reinterpret the bits as a float.

Comment: This is undefined behavior, as rex pointed. out. I'm skipping the fact, that `sizeof(float)` might be different from `sizeof(int)`. Code doing the same with union trick is also undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

The following statement:

> `*(float*)&l;`

uses the

- `&` address-of,
- `*` indirection and
- `(float*)` c-style cast,

operators.

All of these operators are 3rd on list of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and they are all read from right to left.

So first the address of `l` is taken. Next, that address is casted to a `float*` (float pointer). And then finally this address is dereferenced with `*` to read the value. This last step is undefined behavior.

This is undefined behavior for violating the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). It might make a cup of tea for you or it might reinterpret the bits as a float.

On my system the following happens:
At the address of `l` (little endian):

```
0x000000FC780FFC94  0a 00 00 00
```

At the address of `m`:

```
0x0000004547B5F874  0a 00 00 00
```

`l`, interpreted as `int` is: 10

`m`, interpreted as `float` is: 1.401e-44#DEN

The reason for this result (on my system) is that `int` and `float` are the same size (4 bytes on msvc 64 bit) and the float, [interpreted from binary](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) 1010 is 1.401e-44#DEN:

[image]

Comment: The program violates the strict aliasing rule, that's for sure, because `&l` is converted to another pointer type and then dereferenced.

Comment: For future readers: To make the trick well-defined one could use `memcpy(&m, &l, sizeof (int))` with something like `static_assert(sizeof (int) == sizeof (float))`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Interesting. Nice to know there is a way to make it well defined. I suppose it would be fairly portable assuming the systems use the same encoding for floating point? Or perhaps fully portable?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's fully portable. But reading from `m` afterwards can be undefined if it happens to be a trap representation.

Answer (score 1):

First, a warning: According to the C++ Standard, this is undefined behavior. The compiler is free to make the program do *anything* when it executes this line, and in many cases it will not do what the programmer expects. However, for those who are familiar with C++, there is a clear meaning about what was *intended*, and in most cases the compiler will *probably* do that.

First, let’s examine what happens if you just use `(float)l`, as expected. The program will take the value of `l`, interpreted as an `int`, and return a floating-point number with the same value; in this case, that’s `10.0`. This is usually what you want, and is perfectly well-defined.

Now, let’s look at the code you actually have: `*(float*)&l;`. Based on the particular syntax of this expression, it should be read right-to-left. The `&l` part means “get the location where `l` is stored in memory”, usually called a “pointer to `l`”. Because `l` is an `int`, the type of this expression is “pointer to `int`”.

Then, the `(float*)` part is a cast. It says “Treat this pointer-to-`int` as a pointer-to-`float`”. This should be a pointer to the same location in memory, but when the program accesses it, it will read the bits at that location as a `float`.

The first `*` dereferences this pointer-to-`float`, and gets a `float` out. This is the part which is undefined; the language assumes you won’t access the same pointer as two different types. It’s called “pointer aliasing”, and depending on the platform, compiler, optimization flags, etc. can do anything. The *intended* behavior is probably to get the `float` with the same bit pattern as the `int` with value 10.

To see what this means, we need to go into how `float`s and `int`s are stored at the hardware level. An `int` is just stored as a binary number with the same value, with [some complications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) around negative numbers. A `float` is [more complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), and there are even more complications if `float`s and `int`s are stored with different [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

The most likely value of `f` is, as [described by rex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45149764/27302), 1.4e-44 (that is, 1.4  times ten to the negative 44). Another reasonable value would be about 6.16e-33, if `float`s and `int`s had different endianness.